# PostgreSQL not SELECTing by RETURNING value of INSERT

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that's supposed to insert a new row, then return it. Normally a `RETURNING` would suffice, but there's a lot of other `JOIN`ed data must be added, so a `SELECT` seems to be necessary after the `INSERT`.

In this simplified example `id` is a `SERIAL`:

```
WITH new_row AS (
  INSERT INTO my_table (
    some_row,
    some_other_row
  ) VALUES (
    0,
    'whatever'
  ) RETURNING id
)

SELECT
   my_table.*,
   other_table.*
FROM my_table
LEFT JOIN other_table ON other_table.somekey = my_table.id

WHERE my_table.id = (SELECT id FROM new_row)
```

The result is an empty set. Apparently `WHERE` doesn't work.

If I just do this:

```
WITH new_row AS (
  INSERT INTO my_table (
    some_row,
    some_other_row
  ) VALUES (
    0,
    'whatever'
  ) RETURNING id
)

SELECT id FROM new_row;
```

then I get the value of `id` correctly.

Why doesn't it work in the `WHERE` condition?

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that the insert (that happens in the CTE) in not visible (via the `my_table` snapshot) in the main query at that time.

So you could finish first the CTE and then select for example from a temporary table

> ```
> CREATE tABLE my_table(id serIAL,some_row
>  INT, some_other_row varchar(199))
> ```

> ```
> WITH new_row AS (
>   INSERT INTO my_table (
>     some_row,
>     some_other_row
>   ) VALUES (
>     0,
>     'whatever'
>   ) RETURNING id
> )
> SELECT new_row.id INTO films_recent  FROM new_row;
> SELECT
>    my_table.*
> FROM my_table
> WHERE my_table.id = (SELECT id FROM films_recent)
> ```
>
> ```
> 1 rows affected
>
> id | some_row | some_other_row
> -: | -------: | :-------------
>  1 |        0 | whatever
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0cd03d2eaa82b8a6c3233e930a8a63a9)*

---

Or use `new_row` in the main query, which makes the insert changes visible!:

> ```
> WITH new_row AS (
>   INSERT INTO my_table (
>     some_row,
>     some_other_row
>   ) VALUES (
>     0,
>     'whatever'
>   ) RETURNING *
> )
> SELECT
>    new_row.*
> FROM new_row ;
> ```

---

It's like a schrödinger cat, the new row can be visible or not ;)

Comment: Basically we  can see in the question, that the insert was not executed when the SELECT statement was done. We see also that A SELECT * FROM new_rrowyields a result., so it is i a schrödinger cat problem, that an nsert was wade but is nit in the Database , but in the scope of the CTE still gives a result, this is like a transaction that wasn't  comitted, if there is a better Solution in wording, ok change the answer, but it is still correct

Comment: Made an edit, please review. I like the schrödinger cat analogy!

Answer (score 1):

This works (see fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5d683cedda863d0355b8ff55bf3c3ef0)):

```
WITH new_row AS (
  INSERT INTO my_table (
    some_row,
    some_other_row
  ) VALUES (
    4000,
    'sor_400'
  ) RETURNING *
)
SELECT
   mt.id AS mt_id, mt.some_row AS mt_sr, mt.some_other_row AS mt_sor,
   ot.somekey AS ot_sk, ot.other_stuff AS ot_os
FROM new_row mt
LEFT JOIN other_table ot
  ON ot.somekey = mt.id
;
```

Note the ordering of the tables - put `new_row` at the beginning in the `FROM` clause.

Why? It's apparently due to the fact that in a `WITH` clause, only changed/new values from `RETURNING` are visible within that statement. At the point at which you try to match with the new row in `my_table`, it isn't visible yet *within the statement*.

You have to `JOIN` the `id` in `new_row` CTE "table" to the `other_table` (`somekey` field) and not to the new row (note, no `_`) in `my_table` (which isn't visible yet).

In other words, using the newly inserted results (`new_row`) instead of the table snaphsot (`my_table`) solves this because the snapshot does not include the inserted rows -- it was taken before the query started and thus before the insert.

See [WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

> The sub-statements in `WITH` are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in `WITH`, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same *snapshot* (see [Chapter 13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html)), so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables. This alleviates the effects of the unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, and means that `RETURNING` data is the only way to communicate changes between different `WITH` sub-statements and the main query.

---

I find that the most helpful way of thinking about this is to consider the entire thing  - CTE(s) + final (main) SQL - as all part of **one statement** (one **query** - even though there may be many `SELECT`s and/or other clauses) and not as **one transaction**. This means that the underlying tables on disk won't be updated until that **statement/query** commits at the very end of the whole thing - and we can see this when we query the table in a new section after `INSERT`ing in the previous section.